# Running an asynchronous function 'in the background'

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have several asynchronous functions. If I call `main()`, I can't use the second `check()` function, because `main()` runs continuously in a while loop. Can I run `main()` 'in the background' to make the rest of the functions available?

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    while True:
        # update database

async def check():
    # confirm update

async def process(command):
    if command == "main":
        await main()
    elif command == "check":
        await check()
```

Comment: To make them available to what? Where do you want to call them from?

Comment: @RandomDavis `main` and` check` are bot commands

Answer (score 7):

> Can I run main() 'in the background' to make the rest of the functions available?

Yes, you can replace `await main()` with `asyncio.create_task(main())`. That will spawn `main` as a task that effectively runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really asking, is how to achieve concurrency (several coroutines/"things" running simultaneously).  You can achieve concurrency using background tasks as the first answer suggests.

However, that strategy ends up easily in a mess (well, concurrency *always* ends up in mess): you might get "runaway" background tasks you didn't know are still running, background tasks that manipulate the same data structures, resulting in surprises, your program's logic might also depend if tasks are finished or not (in order to fire up different tasks) and then you start messing around with asyncio.wait and asyncio.gather.  It's a road to hell, really.

So, I'm advertising here shamelessly a thing I wrote in order to solve these issues: [TaskThread](https://elsampsa.github.io/task_thread/_build/html/index.html).  It's been a real life safer: you can run tons of simultaneous background tasks, but they are under control & well organized.

Comment: TaskThread seems to be similar to [asyncio.TaskGroup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.TaskGroup) from Python 3.11 to me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  But TaskThread is so much more than just waiting for a bunch of tasks simultaneously. :)