# Python - return from function without waiting function to finish

Tags: python, asynchronous, jobs

I am building an rest API in Python. I am using Connexion Flask. When user called the endpoint providing the input parameter, I need to return the JobId to the user from the endpoint. However, in the background, I am looking to run a async function that will process some functionality.

I looked into Asyncio but all the examples I see are allowing me to run concurrently but the function still needs to be completed before return the JobId value.

Example Code:

```
def inputJob(String inputValue) -> Response
  response = {}  
  response ['job_id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
  response ['inputValue'] = inputValue
  response ['creation_time'] = fnow 
  run_in_background(inputValue)
  return response
```

In this case, I want to return response object to the endpoint without waiting "run_in_background" function to finish. Can someone please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running an asynchronous function 'in the background'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65904964/running-an-asynchronous-function-in-the-background)

Comment: Thanks. No It doesn't. I saw this earlier. If I replace "run_in_background" with asyncio.create_task(self.run_in_background(inputValue)), I go with different errors. For instance, first I will get RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'run_in_background' was never awaited, RuntimeError: no running event loop. If I use event_loop, I get different error

Comment: Well then you have more problems, but that is the answer to your question.

Comment: The other example is also different than mine. The example you posted has no other code after calling main function, so that's bit easy. In my case, I still want to return response to the user after calling the background function

Comment: Yes. So you write `create_task(run_in_background(inputValue))` which goes off to run `run_in_background` in the background, and after that you write `return response`, which returns `response` while `run_in_background` is running in the background.

Comment: I wish it would have worked. It throws me "RuntimeError: no running event loop"

Comment: From the error message I guess you need to start an event loop in which to run the asynchronous functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243658/discussion-between-muhammad-khojaye-and-mkrieger1).

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to solve this with multithreading.
here is an simple example for you hope it will help you.

```
import threading
def waitForASec():
    count = 0
    while(count < 100000000):
        count +=1

    print("hello world")

def main_process():
      t1 = threading.Thread(target=waitForASec, name='t1')
      t1.start()
      return "cool"

print(main_process())
```